# laravel VerifyCsrfToken excepts url with wildcard?

Tags: php, api, middleware, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I try to build my own API. I begin so my only model for the moment will be a "User". Here is how I would like to call my API :

```
HTTP/POST http://example.com/api/user/         # get all the users
HTTP/POST http://example.com/api/user/1        # get the user with id "1"
HTTP/POST http://example.com/api/user/1/delete # delete the user with id "1"
...
```

So my file `routes/web.php` looks like this :

```
<?php    
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function() {
            Route::post('/', 'ApiController@allUsers');
        });
    });
?>
```

But it will not works as I do not pass throught `Route::resource` static method, but with regular `Route::post` method. So the issue is that `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware will trigger and try to check for my CSRF token, but as I want my api to be consume in the future by many other advice I prefer to use my own secure system (which will be a public-private key pairs, but now I just want to check for the integrity of the data I distribute through the api, and I will then set the secure algorithm).

The good news is that Laravel is so clean and let you add your exceptions URL in the `VerifyCSRFToken` array which is shaped like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/user',
        'api/user/{howCanIManageTheWildCard}',
        'api/user/{howCanIManageTheWildCard}/delete',
        ...
    ];
}

?>
```

**Question :**

You see on the middleware above I have 2 issues :

1. I will have to set manually all my routes (which at the end can be long)
2. I do not know if the middleware will be able to handle any wildcard

So can I come with a solution wich could let me do a url wildcard like `api/*` ? Like this it would be so much easier !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can exclude URLs with `/*`

Eg.
instead of `api/user` you can use `api/user/*`

read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Just a suggestion

since you are building an API using laravel you can put all your API routes in `api.php` routes file instead of `web.php` routes file, In that case you will not have to pass **CSRF Token** for post request on API routes.
And all the API routes will be like `example.com/api/<route>` by default, you will not have to group it.
you can read more about Laravel routing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

happy to help :):):)

Comment: BTW did you move your API routes to `api.php` file, that's recommended... @Zeratops

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we use simple URL or Sometimes **URL/Route** carries some value. so that type of situation you can use these two codes. change code in a file

> App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php and $except =[]
>
> for simple Route

```
$except =['http://127.0.0.2/oams/public/oams/payment/success']
```

> for dynamic Route

```
 // http://127.0.0.2/oams/public/oams/payment/{RandCode}/success
$except =['http://127.0.0.2/oams/public/oams/payment/*']
```